# Eliminate RootResourceURI root error

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have written a dropwizard server application with a AMQP listener.It does not have any Root resource as it does not need one.When I start the app I get the below annoying below error.Is there a way to configure jersey to eliminate the error

```
ERROR [2014-03-22 19:37:14,583] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules: The ResourceConfig instance does   
not contain any root resource classes.
! com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init> (RootResourceUriRules.java:99) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1331) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:1    68) ~[jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue for me: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/577#issuecomment-42886757

Answer (score 0):

Saw this thread which will solve the problem

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dropwizard-user/R_CvQX179MY/Oe__pm_K6yQJ